# Checking if a WIN32 / Unmanaged DLL is loaded from a COM module on runtime

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, dll, com

I want to check if a native dll is already loaded from a COM Module? My purpose is to check if the appropriate DLL is loaded so that I can call the corresponding methods on it. I referred the link "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx" but it did not help. My native module is also not shown in the Loaded Module list window in visual studio during debugging but it is shown when I set "Enable native code debugging"? is there a way to achieve the same through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`GetModuleHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199.aspx) passing the module's name. If the module is loaded in your process, a non-null value is returned.

Comment: Thank you very much. it helped me. :)

Comment: This API call is really setting yourself up for a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race condition. [GetModuleHandleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200.aspx), on the other hand, is capable of performing the same check, but locks the module into memory by increasing its ref count. The returned handle can then be safely used in subsequent calls to [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: Excellent point, it may not be necessary given COM's design though. [`DllCanUnloadNow (...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is used to determine whether any references remain. Acquiring a reference should be all that is necessary to keep the module alive.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem like this :

```
private bool IsNativDllLoaded(string dllName) 
{ 
    IntPtr module = GetModuleHandle(dllName); 
    return module != IntPtr.Zero; 
}
```