# How to find out in unmanaged code if it is running in managed context

Tags: winapi, excel-interop

I am writing an Excel VSTO add-in. This add-in loads and runs unmanaged code.

In the startup code of the unmanaged dll, an invisible window for request handling is created. This function call causes a managed exception (LoaderLock) and if I remove it, everything works. I want to avoid creating an extra version just because of this. **Is there a way for the unmanaged code to find out at runtime whether it is running in a managed thread?** In this case, I could add a runtime check. The window is only needed in a fully unmanaged environment.

Note 1: The issue only occurs in this Excel add-in; a stand-alone managed console application using the unmanaged dll does not show this problem.

Note 2: I know that there are many things that should not be done from within DllMain. What I am doing has been working for more than a decade in managed and unmanaged environments and I want to keep code changes as small as possible.

Comment: You should define exactly what do you mean by "running in a managed context".

Comment: "this window is only needed...", but that's of course the exact scenario that produced loader lock.  The oracle you're looking for won't prevent it, you really do have to stop doing dangerous things in dllmain.  Instead start a thread, which then creates the window and runs the message loop.

Comment: Changed "context" and "environment" to thread.

Answer (score -3):

Checking if mscoree.dll has been loaded has done the trick for me:

```
if (::GetModuleHandleW(L"mscoree.dll") == nullptr)
```

This: [Checking if a WIN32 / Unmanaged DLL is loaded from a COM module on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913900/checking-if-a-win32-unmanaged-dll-is-loaded-from-a-com-module-on-runtime) and this: [What does it mean when code "runs on" the .NET CLR?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245938/what-does-it-mean-when-code-runs-on-the-net-clr) helped.
As exposed in the comments below, this does not tell which type of thread has loaded the dll, but only whether there is any managed component in the process. A more precise check would still be preferred. For the moment, I can live with this solution.

Comment: That merely checks whether a module with name `"mscoree.dll"` is currently mapped into the process. You cannot use that to make any assumptions about the environment of the calling thread. It just means that some thread has loaded this module in the past. Nothing more.

Comment: You are absolutely right. In absence of better solutions though, I found that I had to be happy with a more humble and less precise goal. Clarified this in the answer text.